# UIControl sometimes (but not always) firing up action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicontrol

The surrounding:
I've got `class MyClass : NSObject`, that has `NSDictionary *data` and `UIView *myView`. 
In `MyViewController` I've got `MyClass *myObject = [MyClass alloc] init]` and I want to add `UIControl`, so when a user tap it, an action(`someAction:(DifferentClass)sender`) will fire up.

Via sender I send the dictionary to be able to do anything with the data. That's why I have to put `UIControl` on `myClass` not `myClass.myView`.

The problem:
`myAction` is working sometimes, sometimes not. It depends where I click. I've made `[myClass.myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]`, so I'm sure I'm clicking on the place that `UIControl`'s action should work... but they usually work on the left side of the view, while on right they don't work.

Note:
I'm sure the views are correctly settled by `[allViewsInProgram setClipsToBounds:YES]`. I've also tested on simulator with Color offscreen rendered on, there are no bugs.

```
[(UIControl*)myClass addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(myAction:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

Comment: If it is location-specific, I would guess that there's some view, possibly transparent, that's sitting on top of `myClass` and intercepting the touches that should hit `myClass`. Could you give us some more information about other views that exist in the hierarchy, please?

Comment: "there are no bugs" - Always a dangerous assertion.

Comment: @Kevin: There were no bugs shown on layers on simulator color offscreen rendered on - i don't claim there are no bugs in code (i would say there must be some bug because it's not working). Still, simulator didn't help, didn't find any bug.

Comment: @Paul: There are multiple views, i'm still checking them all because i had the same idea- there is something, added on top of them, what is userInteractionEnabled false or taking away the touches.

Comment: If userInteractionEnabled is false, the touches will fall through to the views under that view. You should check to see which ones have user interaction enabled, because those will capture touch events.

Comment: Good to know, i've always thought that userInteractionEnabled false means it'll block events not pass them to underlying views. Thanks for info.